# Checking if a navmesh path is blocked takes too long

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple tower defence game for mobile. I've written a function to check if placing a tower would prevent the enemies from reaching their goal:

```
public bool CheckPathNotBlocked(Vector3 pos)
{
    navmesh_obstacle_tester.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    navmesh_obstacle_tester.position = pos;
    NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();
    botsInPlay[botsInPlay.Count - 1].CalculatePath(enemyBase.position, path);
    navmesh_obstacle_tester.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    return path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete;
}
```

The navmesh_obstacle_tester is an empty GameObject with a NavMeshObstacle attached. The botsInPlay is a list of enemy NavMeshAgents so I'm using the most recently spawned enemy to check the path. This actually works but not in time to prevent my tower from being placed:

```
public void PlaceTower(Vector3 pos, int tType)
{
    if (!F_BotsManager.bots.CheckPathNotBlocked(pos)) return;

    // rest of my code to place a tower
}
```

The function exits if the path is completely blocked but does not exit before placing the tower that will block the path e.g. once I've formed a ring of towers around all the enemies no more towers can be placed, but the final tower that completes the ring is placed.

I have read [in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.SetDestination.html) that path calculation can take a few frames, could this be the cause of the problem? How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You did not show how and where the PlaceTower function is being called. This is really important to figure out how to help.

> How can I resolve the issue?

Anything that takes so long to do and you have to wait for it in Unity should be done with a coroutine or a Thread, depending on the thing. In this case, coroutine should be used to wait it so that other things in your code can continue running.

```
public IEnumerator PlaceTower(Vector3 pos, int tType)
{
    while (!F_BotsManager.bots.CheckPathNotBlocked(pos))
    {
        Debug.Log("waiting!");
        yield return null;
    }

    // rest of my code to place a tower
}
```

Now, anywhere you called this function should now be replaced with  `StartCoroutine(PlaceTower(yourPost,yourIntType));`. You have to refactor your whole code to accommodate the use of coroutine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the CheckPathNotBlocked function is clearly visible in my post! Place tower happens via a mouse click in Fixed Update. Putting CheckPathNotBlocked in a while loop will result in an infinite loop - it returns a bool; the first time it's called the path will never be blocked. I know you're a great coder, you've helped many times in the past - could you please re-read my post? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I just realized that `CheckPathNotBlocked` is in your question. I don't know how I missed that.  *"Putting CheckPathNotBlocked in a while loop will result in an infinite loop"* This would be true in a non coroutine function. This is why I used a coroutine function with `yield return null;`. Please try what's in my answer. It shouldn't be in an infinite loop as long as your `CheckPathNotBlocked` function returns `true` at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I tried as you suggested and there was no infinite loop, but it didn't work, the tower still gets placed. The NavMeshPathStatus = PathComplete on the last tower and only shows Incomplete on subsequent attempts to place a tower. I've tried putting the CheckPathNotBlocked in a different method with an IF statement then calling PlaceTower but it's the same result. I've tried using a NavmeshAgent on the spawn point instead of the last enemy spawned, still the same. I've altered the settings on the NavMesh obstacle in every possible combination but no joy. Any ideas?